# Button Function Not Working?

Tags: java, swing, button, static

So I am trying to write a program using swing components so whenever the user clicks on a button, a different word shows up in the text box. I keep getting an error saying "non static method buttons() cannot be referenced from a static context" I checked other answers on how to fix it with the same error, but I still don't understand it. it appears here:

> color.buttons();

And this is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class color {
    private JFrame f;
    private JLabel label;
    private JPanel controlPanel;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;
    private JTextField textbox;

    public color() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        color c = new color();
        color.buttons();
    }
    private void prepareGUI() {
        f = new JFrame("Colors");
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        label = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setBounds(20, 105, 200, 25);

        textbox = new JTextField("", JTextField.CENTER);
        textbox.setBounds(20, 75, 125, 50);

        f.add(label);
        f.add(textbox);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void buttons() {
        label.setText("Click a Button to Reveal Text");
        textbox.setText("Which Color?");

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Blue");
        button1.setBounds(10, 305, 120, 75);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Red");
        button2.setBounds(140, 305, 120, 75);
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Yellow");
        button3.setBounds(270, 305, 120, 75);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                textbox.setText("Blue");
            }
        });
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                textbox.setText("Red");
            }
        });
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                textbox.setText("Yellow");
            }
        });

        controlPanel.add(button1);
        controlPanel.add(button2);
        controlPanel.add(button3);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `c.buttons()` instead of `color.buttons()`

Comment: You need to write `c.buttons()` not `color.buttons()`. I hope before venturing into the world of `Swing`, you are familiar with the basic concepts of `Object Oriented Programming` :-) `color.buttons()` means that `buttons()` method is static, and `ClassName` is used to refer to it, by convention, though `object/instance of a class` is used to refer to non-static thingies

Answer (score 2):

You should try `c.buttons();` instead of `color.buttons();`

As non static methods can not be directly referenced, you need an object to do that.

Where as if the method is static then you can use `color.buttons();`.

Answer (score 2):

The `static` declaration is used when a field is [associated with a class, rather than with any particular object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). Now, let's consider your code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    color c = new color();
    color.buttons();
}
```

Of course, the main method *has* to be `static` in order to initially run your code. By extension, everything within your `static` main method must also be `static` or in other words must be able to run without being directly associated with any object. Therefore, you cannot call `color.buttons()` since the method is not a `static` method.

You have two solutions:

1. Make the method `static`. Of course, it might not actually make sense to make it `static` in this case but sometimes in other cases it might be appropriate.
2. Call the method in the new, instantiated color object, `c`, as such: `c.buttons();` OR call `buttons()` inside the constructor `color()`.

For clarity, the second solution, in your code, would look like the following:

```
public color() {
    prepareGUI();
    buttons();
}
```

OR

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    color c = new color();
    c.buttons();
}
```

Calling `c.buttons()` inside of the `static` main method is possible since the `buttons()` method is a method associated with the instantiated object, `c`.

Finally, some best practices and tips:

1. You should read the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and apply it to your code. For example, your class should be capitalized to be `Color` instead of `color`. Following naming conventions makes it easier for other people to read your code because naming conventions are a sort of contract that developers agree on.
2. You should not call Java Swing methods outside of the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) as most Swing methods are not thread-safe. Calling Swing methods outside the EDT may result in hard-to-find problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a non-static method from a static method in java.
In your case, you are trying to call method buttons() which is a non-static method, where as main method (where you are calling buttons method) is a static method.
Change your main method like this.

```
public static void main (String args[]){
color c = new color();
c.buttons();
}
```

In this way you are calling the member function of an object.